# convert pdf pages to xml through java, i want to convert pdf to xml programatically . any jar files is there

Tags: java-me

I have a pdf document contains so  much of text  equatios , and images .so i want to convert into xml format programatically. I am aware of iText.

Is there any jar files for this?

Comment: NO there is nothing as far I'm aware, plus such task would be to much for JME device in regards of resources. Don't you think?